# How to get JavaScript stack trace with WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control, callstack

Knowing [how to get notified about script errors when hosting a `WebBrowser` control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261003/en-us) using `OLECMDID_SHOWSCRIPTERROR` inside my WinForms C# application, I currently do it successfully this way:

```
private void handleError(mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument)
{
    var htmlWindow = htmlDocument.parentWindow;
    var htmlEventObject = htmlWindow.@event as mshtml.IHTMLEventObj2;

    _lineNumber = (int)htmlEventObject.getAttribute(@"errorLine");
    _characterNumber = (int)htmlEventObject.getAttribute(@"errorCharacter");
    _errorCode = (int)htmlEventObject.getAttribute(@"errorCode");
    _errorMessage = htmlEventObject.getAttribute(@"errorMessage") as string;
    _url = htmlEventObject.getAttribute(@"errorUrl") as string;
}
```

This works as expected.

What I currently cannot solve is to get the JavaScript call stack.

I've tried several things in the example above:

```
_callStack = htmlEventObject.getAttribute(@"stack") as string;
_callStack = htmlEventObject.getAttribute(@"errorStack") as string;
_callStack = htmlEventObject.getAttribute(@"stackTrace") as string;
...
```

All those do return an empty/NULL string.

Whether I'm [unsure if this information can be retrieved at all](http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/), still **my question is**:

How to get the call stack of a JavaScript error from within the application hosting an Internet Explorer web browser control?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if that's possible at all either, but I might have some useful information related to your question. Back in IE7 days I worked on a custom host for WebBrowser control in C++, and I still keep the list of service GUIDs the control was requesting from my [OLE site object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) through [IServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider.aspx). One of those interfaces was [IDebugApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b12b5czc%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), which might open a door to access JavaScript stack frame via `IDebugApplication::AddStackFrameSniffer`. I had not tried it back then. If you're ready to do further research, you could use [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control) as a starting point to implement a custom WebBrowser host in C#.

Comment: NP but one more thought, you'd probably need to have Script Debugging enabled in IE Advanced option for this to work.